# How did Hawai'ian surnames work during Kamehameha's Act to Regulate Names?

Tags: names

I was wondering how family names were inherited during the Act to Regulate Names in Hawai'i. There's some conflicting info: some sources seem to say that the given name of the father of the person in question became their new family name. However, I need to know if this was passed down as in...

Example A:
Kunui Aka Kamealoha (Grandfather)
Change initiated
Albert Kalani Aka (Father)
Leonard Kanoena Kalani (Son)

or Example B:
Kunui Aka Kamealoha (Grandfather)
Change initiated
Albert Kalani Kunui (Father)
Leonard Kanoena Albert (Son)

or Example C:
Kunui Aka Kamealoha (Grandfather)
Change initiated
Albert Kalani Kunui (Father)
Leonard Kanoena Kunui (Son)

or some other way.

I'm writing an alternate history book, and as always, things get complicated.

Comment: I can't see pattern A or B, since continuous iterations after a given name "**became** their new family name." Not comparing, but *Rinse and Repeat* is universally understood as once and done, and not endless.

Comment: Welcome to the site - this question was migrated from elsewhere, so it doesn't currently meet our normal expectations for  [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).  I believe that this is within scope of H:SE; we've had other discussions about integration of cultural identifiers into the melting pot.  It would help tremendously if we could get a citation for the Act to Regulate Names in Hawai'i, and a date for that act (my google fu isn't good enough). And perhaps the examples explained?

Comment: Is the relevant law [Law on Naming](https://nupepa-hawaii.com/2020/09/09/law-on-naming-1860/)?

Comment: Also, it would help if you could cite some of the "There's some conflicting info: some sources s"  - textual analysis is one of the chief tools of history, and we can't do that without texts. Those sources would also help to clarify the examples

Comment: Reading the "Law on Naming" link, it is indeed ambiguous, because it just says "father's name", without specifying what _part_ of the father's name...

Comment: I strongly suspect it is the father's surname